# Shift Differentials

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to figure how many hours are worked between certain times.
Example, employees get a pay increase for any hours between 11pm-5am. So if a employee comes in 2am and works till 10am,employee will receive 3 hours of pay increase. any hours worked between 11pm and 5am need to be calculated so they get the pay difference. I can quickly do the math in my head but there are several shifts.
Is a formula?

Comment: What version of Excel? Do your time stamps include both data and time, or only the time? Can a person work 24 or more consecutive hours?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it direct in cells, by breaking dates to common elements month day years and doing the individual math there, and then can break the days to 24 hour and do the same. Or using intrinsic functions, depends on your style.

Using

```
=DAY(DATE(2023, 8, 15))
=MONTH(DATE(2023, 8, 15))
=YEAR(DATE(2023, 8, 15))
```

Or using **DATEDIFF()**
Examples:

```
Start_date    End_date   Formula                       

1/1/2001      1/1/2003   =DATEDIF(Start_date,End_date,"Y")    Two complete years in the period (2)
        
6/1/2001      8/15/2002  =DATEDIF(Start_date,End_date,"D")    440 days between June 1, 2001, and August 15, 2002 (440)
        
6/1/2001      8/15/2002   =DATEDIF(Start_date,End_date,"YD")  75 days between June 1 and August 15, ignoring the years of the dates (75)
```

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/datedif-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c

and then to get time, it will do that for you with simple math like A1-A2, it sees they are times if the cell format is time, and does the rest. if they are text you can convert them and do the same

```
=TIMEVALUE(“8:30 PM”) – TIMEVALUE(“6:40 AM”)
```

full write up and examples here https://traqq.com/blog/how-to-calculate-time-difference-in-excel/

Comment: You should mention that the `DATEDIF` function is not a fully supported Excel function, and explain how it helps solve the OP's problem (IMO it does not). Your mention of the `TIMEVALUE` function is incomplete as it requires the OP to record time in that specific way (which is not known), and because the OP mentions time that crosses over days that may give negative results depending on the times worked and how the OP records time in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Date diff was mentioned because i mention a wide array of date math, time is one of them, but the others will lily become relevant in a project as they describe. teach a man to fish...